# qgis processing not add layer

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, grass-gis

I'm currently writing a python plugin where I would like user with 0 experience of GIS to use QGIS to view data geographically anyhow,

I'm running two `processing` functions:

```
import processing
processing.runandload('qgis:reprojectlayer', str(self.input_file_path) + "shapefiles/temp.shp",'EPSG:4326', file_name + '.shp')
processing.runandload("grass:v.voronoi", file_name+".shp",False, True, extent, -1, 0, 3, file_name_poly)
```

Both of them are adding the new layer in qgis "Layers Panel", can I turn this off? (and just saving the files in the selected path). Now I got one layer called Reprojected and one called Voronoi Polygons in the Layer Panel.

Comment: You mean turn off visibility or you want to do changes on same shape files ?

Comment: I don't want them to appear in the layer list, sorry for being unclear!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace the `runandload` function with `runalg` if you don't want the output to be shown. So your code will look like:

```
import processing
processing.runalg('qgis:reprojectlayer', str(self.input_file_path) + "shapefiles/temp.shp",'EPSG:4326', file_name + '.shp')
processing.runalg("grass:v.voronoi", file_name+".shp",False, True, extent, -1, 0, 3, file_name_poly)
```